# argparse: optional argument overwriting positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have a python script with arguments `foo [--bar baz]` and want to add an optional argument/switch `--extra-info` that would just print some extra information and exit. (My actual use case is bit more complicated, but this illustrates the issue.)

I found the following solution, but it looks more like a hack. Basically, I am making the positional argument optional if '--extra-info' is present in the argument list:

```py
import sys
import argparse

parser.add_argument('--extra-info', action='store_true')
pos_nargs = '?' if '--extra-info' in sys.argv else None
parser.add_argument('foo', nargs=pos_nargs)
parser.add_argument('--bar')
```

Is there a better approach to this?
I would expect there to be one, given that `--help` behaves exactly the way I want my switch to behave...

Comment: I'd handle the check after all arguments have been parsed.  Then just check if extra info was specified, and make the appropriate check for the positional arguments.

Comment: `help` uses an `Action` subclass that displays its info and exits.  There is 'version' subclass that does the same, but with a custom message.  Use that or define your own subclass that copies it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action - I don't know how much custom `version` info you can orovide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the command line in 2 passes: The first pass is to parse `--extra-info`, the second will parse the rest.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--extra-info", action="store_true")
options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()

if options.extra_info:
    print("Show extra information")
    sys.exit()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("foo")
parser.add_argument("--bar")
# Add here for the help text only
parser.add_argument("--extra-info", action="store_true", help="blah")
options = parser.parse_args(remainder)
print(options)
```

Some interactions:

```bash
# Show help
$ ./main.py 
usage: main.py [-h] [--bar BAR] [--extra-info] foo
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: foo

# Show extra info
$ ./main.py --extra-info
Show extra information

# specify foo/bar
$ ./main.py myfoo --bar mybar
Namespace(foo='myfoo', bar='mybar', extra_info=False)
```

#### Notes

- In the first pass, I used `parse_known_args` just to parse `--extra-info`. The `remainder` holds those command-line arguments which the first-pass parser does not understand. We will use this remainder in the second pass.
- In the second pass, I added `--extra-info` simply for the help/usage.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the `version` action class, in an ipython session.

I added `RawTextHelpFormatter` to allow for multiple lines in the version text.

```
In [125]: import argparse
     ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTex
     ...: tHelpFormatter)
     ...: txt = 'this is some extra info\nlets try a second line'
     ...: parser.add_argument('--extra-info', action='version', version=tx
     ...: t)
     ...: parser.add_argument('foo')
     ...: parser.add_argument('--bar');
```

with extra:

```
In [126]: parser.parse_args('--bar xyz fooarg --extra-info'.split())
this is some extra info
lets try a second line
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. <this is ipython exit capture>
```

without extra:

```
In [127]: parser.parse_args('--bar xyz fooarg'.split())
Out[127]: Namespace(foo='fooarg', bar='xyz')
```

Most `Action` subclasses have a `__call__` method that writes something to the `args` namespace, and returns.  The `help` and `version` classes print something, and issue a system exit, thus terminating all remaining parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [hpaulj' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962527/argparse-optional-argument-overwriting-positional-arguments#comment135675063_76962527), I managed to make it work with an custom action:

```py
import sys
import argparse

class XInfoAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=0, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("Show extra information")
        sys.exit(0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--extra-info", action=XInfoAction, help="prints extra info")
parser.add_argument("foo")
parser.add_argument("--bar")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

This gives exactly the same output as [Hai Vu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76963226/842693), but I find this approach more elegant.

Note that one could drop defining `__init__()`, at the cost of having to add `nargs=0` to the definition of the `--extra-info` argument - as far as I can see, this is just a manner of taste...